# What is wrong with my ftp code?

Tags: c#, ftp

I am using c# in .NEt 2.0 to simply try to upload a file. Everything seems ok in the code, but it keeps failing at when I go to create a stream from the FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream method.

Here is the code...

```
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
        FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;

        try
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(strCompleteFilePath);
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://myhost/" + fileName));
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myUserID", "myPW");
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;

            FileInfo ff = new FileInfo(strCompleteFilePath);
            byte[] fileContents = new byte[ff.Length];

            using (FileStream fr = ff.OpenRead()) 
            {
                fr.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(ff.Length));
            }

            using (Stream writer = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                writer.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            }

            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse(); 
        }
```

And the error....

```
{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.InvokeRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception e)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

Comment: Sorry, the / before the file name WAS there. I accidentally took it out when posting it. But, when I run the code, and it fails, the / IS there.

Comment: What's the server?  Here's a question about an AS/400 that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930787/ftpwebrequest-connecting-to-an-as-400

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a / in the path.

You are going to be creating a path that is `ftp://myhostmyfile.txt` if your file was called "myfile.txt", which I'm guessing should be `ftp://myhost/myfile.txt`

Therefore just add a / to the end of the `ftp://myhost` string.

Answer (score 4):

This looks wrong:

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://myhost" + fileName));
```

Unless the contents of filename starts with a */* I think you need to add one of those so it would be like:

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://myhost/" + fileName));
```

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://myhost" + fileName));
```

Might be a problem if your `fileName` variable doesn't include the necessary slashes.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP server is unhappy about the STOR command that .NET generates.  Best place to look is in the log file for the server.  Taking a wild guess: the path is unusual, you'd typical want to specify a directory name (like ftp://myhost/somedir/filename)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
```

it works for me.