# FTPWebRequest & AS/400 - Setting NAMEFMT to 1

Tags: .net, ibm-midrange, ftpwebrequest

I'm trying to connect to a FTP AS/400 server using .NET, with a url like this:

```
ftp://server.com/folder/file.csv
```

I'm getting a 501 error in return, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930787/ftpwebrequest-connecting-to-an-as-400)  it's due to the path separator or AS/400 not working with regular paths without setting NAMEFMT to 1.

Since I'm using the FTPWebRequest object, is there any way I can set NAMEFMT to 1 with a FTPWebRequest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to send `SITE NAMEFMT 1` as a `QUOTE` command.

See this related question: [How to send arbitrary ftp commands in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321097).  It doesn't appear to be possible using `FTPWebRequest`.

Take a look at [libcurl.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcurl-net/).

---

Alternatively if you can force `FTPWebRequest` to make the 'first' file or pathname parameter received in a subcommand start with a slash (/) or a tilde (~) character the system will automatically enforce `NAMEFMT 1`.  See [File systems and naming conventions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiq/rzaiqftpconvn.htm) under the [FTP reference information](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiq/rzaiqreference.htm) topic in the IBM i information center.

Comment: If you can make the connection refer to an IFS file (leading slash) it switches to namefmt 1.

Comment: Putting a slash ('/') in front of the file path did the trick. Thanks!